# Google sites liberation: Bad Request Invalid request URI

Tags: gdata, google-sites

I keep getting

```
Jul 24, 2014 11:53:15 AM com.google.sites.liberation.export.ContinuousContentFeed?$FeedIterator? catchException WARNING: Error retrieving response from query. com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException?: Bad Request Invalid request URI

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:558) at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:543) at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:536) at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:515)
```

**I used (you can use this test account i provide the password here below :) ).**

```
 java -jar google-sites-liberation-1.0.4.jar -w https://sites.google.com/site/hmmtestgsl/ -u hmmtestgsl@gmail.com -p aaabbbcccddd -f ./backup
```

and I changed the main in `MANIFEST.MF` to: `Main-Class`: `com.google.sites.liberation.export.Main` so that I can run it from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

> -w hmmtestgsl

instead of

> -w https://sites.google.com/site/hmmtestgsl/

fixed it.